# Trying to get property of non-object error during json encode

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Here is a piece of code i am trying to write. Here i want to retrieve data from the database, store that into an array and then json_ecode it and set is as output. But i keep on getting this error "Trying to get property of non-object".

Here is the code

```
$data['query'] = $this->db->get('forms');

foreach($data['query'] as $row)
{
    $forms_array[] = array(
        $row->id 
    );
}   

$return=json_encode($forms_array);
$this->output->set_output($return);
```

Comment: What line of code actually causes the error output?

Comment: It sounds like $row is not an object then and has nothing to do with your json_encode call.  Have you dumped out the value of $row to see exactly what it is? i.e. did the DB query even work, or did you get some other value (false, NULL, etc.) that represents a query failure or an empty set?

Comment: you are right..m getting some thing as id:null at the end of the page

Comment: but if i put this condition if($data['query']->num_rows() > 0) it returns true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first check that your query is actually returning rows. Secondly, you want to access `$data['query']->result()` in your `foreach`:

```
if($data['query']->num_rows() > 0){
    // The query returned rows...
    foreach($data['query']->result() as $row){
        $forms_array[] = array(
            $row->id 
        );
    } 
}
```

Comment: yes just checked that condition..it is getting more than 0 records

Comment: @user1212207: Please see the edit above. You want to access `$data['query']->result()` in your `foreach`

Comment: @user1212207: Sorry, I forgot to actually add my edit to the code sample. It's there now.

Comment: @user1212207 Still initialize the form_array as empty array. If there are no records found, you will get undefined forms_array........

Comment: @MadanSapkota: While a good point, OP may be doing that already. There is no way to know based on the snippet of code provided.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare $forms_array[] outside the foreach.

Comment: While a good suggestion, this is more of a comment than an answer.